# For some reason, this code is causing all radio buttons to be pre-populated as selected. It is always the last one within the group

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, onload

I have this group of three radio buttons. If the one labelled In-Home is selected, a new form appears on the page to be filled out. That's all working fine. HOWEVER, for some reason, this code is also causing all of the radio button groups to be pre-populated when the page loads. For example, if I have a group of 4 buttons, the 4th one is pre-selected on load, if it's a group of 6, the 6th one is selected on load, and so on throughout the page. I have narrowed it down to this code...

```js
//SHOW/HIDE BACKUP V
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){

    if($(this).attr("value")=="location"){
        $(".Box").hide('slow');
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="hub"){
        $(".Box").hide('slow');
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="inHome"){
        $(".Box").show('slow');

    }        
});
$('input[type="radio"]').trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-6">
  <b><u>Backup Ventilator </u></b><b><u>Interface </u></b><br>
  <span>
  <input id="showBackup" value="location" name="F429_backupAtLocRadio" type="radio">
  </span><span>Location 
  <input id="showBackup" value="hub" name="F429_backupAtLocRadio" type="radio">
  </span><span>Hub 
  <input id="showBackup" class="backUp" value="inHome" name="F429_backupAtLocRadio" type="radio">
  </span>In Home 
</div>
```

Comment: multiple `id="showBackup"` will cause this

Comment: Okay that actually didn't change anything. Still getting same result

Comment: if you dont want it pre-selected then remove this line `$('input[type="radio"]').trigger('click');` :/

Comment: Okay that worked for all the other buttons on the form, but "inHome" is still pre-selected. This is very strange. I also tried setting the radio button to "checked="false". It still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `$('input[type="radio"]').trigger('click');`.
2. Remove the redundant ids from your radio input elements and add/update the class attr on each to a unique class name ex. `class='backup-ventilator-radio'`.
3. Change your click handler selector from `$('input[type="radio"]')` to `$('.backup-ventilator-radio')`.

It sounds like your handler is being triggered by action on the other radio button groups in your dom because the click listener selector is generic.